# Linear program question

Tags: linear-programming

I'm trying to prepare for my midterm and  I was going over some problems out of my algorithm book but can't seem to figure out the following problem:

Find necessary and sufficient conditions on the reals a and b under which the linear program

```
max: x+y
ax + by <=1
x, y =>0
```

(a) is infeasible.
(b) is unbounded.
(c) has a finite and unique optimal solution.

here is what I've come up with:
for (a), we can add another constraint: ax+by=>5

I'm not sure what to do about b and c.I'm not sure If I'm allowed to change the constraints I'm already given or add new ones.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks so much advance.

Comment: This problem sounds to me like you are allowed to choose `a` and `b`, but may not add or otherwise modify any constraints of the program.  Except the part about "necessary and sufficient" means you need to describe a way to determine which of the three cases (if any) applies no matter what `a` and `b` you're given.

Comment: Just curious: is that a "linear program" or a "linear programming model"? You know correct nomenclature is key in this field.

Comment: Should be linear programming model but that's how it is written in my book.

Answer (score 4):

a) I'm not sure if this is possible unless you add a constraint just like you did.
b) if a and b are both less than or equal to zero your problem will be unbounded
c) if a and b are both larger than zero, and they are not equal to each other you will have a unique optimal solution

Comment: More precisely: (a) is never possible without additional constraint, since `(0, 0)` is always feasible. (b) the problem is unbounded if and only if _either_ `a<=0` or `b<=0` (whatever the value of the second coefficient is)

Answer (score 1):

a. This linear program never infeasible. No matter what value of a and b, there is always a feasible solution to satisfy ax + by <= 1

b. This linear program is unbounded when either a <= 0 or b <= 0.

c. Finite and unique optimal solution exist when a != b and both a > 0 and b > 0

Answer (score -1):

For part (a): it is infeasible when either
a=0 and b<0
OR
a<0 and b=0

Comment: I'll leave it as an exercise to @sap to figure out why this answer is wrong.

Comment: a=0, b<0, say -1-> 0*x-1*y <=1 x= 0, y = 1 = -1 <1 ->feasible.